# Writing a .NET console application with GUI wrapper

Tags: .net, user-interface, console

I am writing a .NET console application to upload files. However, I might have to create a GUI front end for this application in the future. How can I best design my console application with this in mind? Passing arguments will be simple, but how can I show progress and errors in the GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your application presentation and logic decoupled.  You can design your application around interfaces.  For example, if you create and use an `IProgress` interface for reporting progress, your console application can use Console.Write to report progress, but your GUI application, later, can just use the same interface to update a progress bar.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that instead of trying to make your console application be the point of integration for a front-end, instead create a common shared library to host all the business logic, and instead integrate your UI at that level.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make the GUI interact with the console app. Separate the logic from interface and make each interface interact with the common logic library(ies)